# $\phi: M_2(\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{Z}$ is necessarily trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $\varphi: M_2(\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{Z}$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $\varphi$ is necessarily trivial.

My reasoning:

Suppose not. Then $\varphi(I)=1\implies \forall A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}),\exists A^{-1}\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\varphi(I)=\phi(A)\phi(A^{-1})=\phi(A)\phi(A)^{-1}=aa^{-1}$. However, only $1$ and $-1$ have multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, if $A\ne I$, then $\phi(A)^{-1}$ may not exist. This implies that $\phi$ must be trivial (that is, map everything to $1$). [For if $\phi(A)=0$ for all $A\ne I$, then $\phi(A)^{-1}$ admits division by $0$].

Do you think this is correct?

Comment: Are all matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ invertible?...

Comment: @Bemte Good point. But some are, and the condition for $\phi^{-1}$ does not hold for them.

Comment: You have proven that, if $\varphi : M_2(\mathbb Z) \to \mathbb Z$ is a ring morphism, then every invertible matrix is sent to $1$ or $-1$. That's interesting, but it doesn't yet prove the result you want.

Comment: @PseudoNeo Since $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is no an integral domain, $\varphi(AB)=\phi(A)\phi(B) = 0 = ab\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $A, B\ne O_2$ then $a,b \ne 0$ thus $A$ and $B$ must be trivially sent to $0$. If $A$ and $B$ are invertible then $A$ and $B$ don't need to be sent to $0$...

Comment: You should always define the objects you're talking about: who are $A$ and $B$ in your comment? Furthermore, you cannot claim that $a, b \neq 0$ without knowing that $\varphi$ is one-to-one.

Comment: @sequence I just posted a new answer in the link of the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi$ be any such morphism. Then $Ker\phi$ is an ideal in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$. But it's a two-sided ideal.

What do ideals in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ look like ?

Assume $Ker\phi$ is not $\{0\}$, and let $M\in Ker\phi$, $M\neq 0$. But then since $Ker\phi$ is an ideal, the matrix consisting of $rk(M)$ times the same integer $k$ (for some $k$) in the top left-hand corner and zeroes elsewhere is also in $Ker\phi$, since the one where $k=1$ is equivalent to $M$ in $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$, and then multiplying by sufficiently large integers does the trick.Then composing with projectors, one gets the matrix with only one $k$ in the top left hand corner, and zeroes elsewhere.

Composing with some pivot matrices gives all the $kE_{i,j}$ (with the usual notations), so that $kM_2(\mathbb{Z})\subset Ker\phi$, which implies $\phi(kI_n)=0$, which in turn gives $k\phi(I_n) =0$. Since $k\neq 0$, this gives $\phi(I_n) =0$, $Ker\phi = M_2(\mathbb{Z})$.  Thus $\phi$ is trivial.

Therefore, we can assume that $Ker\phi = \{0\}$. But then $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic with its image, which is a subring of the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}$. However $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is not commutative, which is a contradiction.

Thus $\phi$ is trivial.

Comment: Can you please clarify the following? *1.* How is $\ker$ related to triviality? That is, why would anyone assume that $\ker\varphi$ is trivial for this proof? I don't follow this. *2.* What is $rk(M)$? I don't know this notation.

I think your proof is a bit complicated. There should be a shorter approach.

Comment: 1. Any ring morphism $f: R\to S$ is trivial if and only if $ker f= R$, injective if and only if $Kerf = \{0\}$. 2. $rk(M)$ is the rank of the matrix $M$, i.e. the dimension of its image (if you look at it as an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}^2$). If $K$ is a field and $M\in M_n(K)$, then there exist $P,Q\in GL_n(K)$ such that $PMQ$ is a matrix with $rk(M)$ ones in the top left hand corner and zeroes elsewhere, that's what I used. Maybe there is a shorter proof, but this one is the first that came to mind.

Comment: Note that when $E$ is a $K$-vector space, $L(E)$ only has trivial (bilateral) ideals (that's what led me to this proof, but here you need to modify it a bit since $\mathbb{Z}$ is only a subring of the field $\mathbb{Q}$), and I think this is the essential reason why this theorem is true.

Comment: If you look at the answers on the same question that has been asked before, there is indeed a shorter proof, but not very general; whereas the second answer gives a proof that is essentially the same as mine, and that is generalizable

Comment: What is $L(E)$?

Comment: The ring of endomorphisms of $E$.

Comment: I see. We didn't cover the concept of endomorphisms in this course. Only homo- and isomorphisms, as well as slightly touched upon automorphisms.